Apply different logic to query a database table and represent it with expanded information
I have a database table below from which I want to write a SQL query that extracts the desired output below.
PRODUCT:



ProductID
RecordID
ProductVersion
ReceivedDate
UrgencyLevel
Resolved
InvestigationDate
ResolvedDate




1
17
1
2001-09-11 17:05:00
NULL
0
NULL
NULL


1
17
10
2001-09-11 17:05:00
6
1
2001-09-11 17:59:00
2001-09-11 20:04:00


2
13
1
2001-12-04 09:05:00
6
0
NULL
NULL


2
13
11
2001-12-04 09:05:00
5
1
2001-12-04 10:19:00
2001-12-04 12:07:00


3
71
1
2001-06-08 12:36:00
5
0
2001-06-08 12:36:00
NULL


3
71
6
2001-06-08 12:36:00
1
1
2001-06-08 12:36:00
2001-06-08 13:21:00


4
10
1
2001-05-01 11:00:00
1
0
2001-05-01 12:00:00
2001-05-01 12:30:00


4
10
3
2001-05-01 11:00:00
1
1
2001-05-01 12:15:00
NULL


5
21
1
2001-07-23 09:00:00
8
0
2001-07-23 10:15:00
NULL


5
21
15
2001-07-23 09:00:00
NULL
0
2001-05-23 10:30:00
NULL



Each ProductID has a ProductVersion = 1 (minimum version) and a second ProductVersion (the maximum version). ReceivedDate is always the same for each unique ProductID. Furthermore, ReceivedDate is never NULL but ResolvedDate can be NULL.
DurationInMinutes is calculated as ReceivedDate - ResolvedDate on the maximum version. If ResolvedDate on maximum ProductVersion is NULL, then use the ResolvedDate on the minimum ProductVersion, otherwise assign NULL to DurationInMinutes.
The Resolved column is usually 0 on minimum version, and 1  on maximum version, however in certain circumstances (e.g. for ProductID 5) we may have the value of 0 on both product versions. In such cases we want to enforce the value of Resolved on the maximum version to be 1 instead of 0.
Desired output:



ProductID
RecordID
ReceivedDate
FirstUrgencyLevel
FinalUrgencyLevel
FirstInvestigationDate
FinalInvestigationDate
DurationInMinutes




1
17
2021-09-11 17:05:00
NULL
6
NULL
2001-09-11 17:59:00
179


2
13
2001-12-04 09:05:00
6
5
NULL
2001-12-04 10:19:00
182


3
71
2001-06-08 12:36:00
5
1
2001-06-08 12:36:00
2001-06-08 12:36:00
45


4
10
2001-05-01 11:00:00
1
1
2001-05-01 12:00:00
2001-05-01 12:15:00
90


5
21
2001-07-23 09:00:00
8
NULL
2001-07-23 10:15:00
2001-07-23 10:30:00
NULL



I have tried the below but I don't seem to get the desired output. Furthermore, how can I incorporate the different logic described above to get my desired output.
select 
    ProductID,
    RecordID,
    ReceivedDate,
    case 
        when UrgencyLevel = 0 then UrgencyLevel 
    end as FirstUrgencyLevel,
    case 
        when UrgencyLevel = 1 then UrgencyLevel 
    end as FinalUrgencyLevel,
    case 
        when UrgencyLevel = 0 then InvestigationDate 
    end as FirstInvestigationDate,
    case 
        when UrgencyLevel = 1 then InvestigationDate 
    end as FinalInvestigationDate,
    datediff(minute,ReceivedDate, ResolvedDate) as DurationInMinutes
from 
    PRODUCT


You can

Use the MAX(...) OVER(...) window function to identify the last ProductVersion for each group of input rows. This can be wrapped up in a common table expression for later use. (A window function allows you to calculate an aggregated value without using a GROUP BY.)
Use a CROSS APPLY to tag the first row defined as ProductVersion = 1 and the final row defined as ProductVersion = MaxProductVersion. (Using a CROSS APPLY to encapsulate this logic is optional, but having separating calculations can make for a cleaner select list.)
From there, you can group by ProductID and RecordID and use conditional aggregation to select your final results.  (Conditional aggregation is a technique that uses an aggregation function like COUNT(), SUM(), or MAX() together with a conditional CASE expression or IIF() function to selectively include or exclude values in the result. If the condition is true, the THEN value is included. If false, the implied ELSE NULL is ignored.)
For the DurationInMinutes calculation, we need to extract both the first and final ResolvedDate and use COALESCE() to choose the preferred value (final before first) to feed into the DATEDIFF() calculation.

The resulting query would be something like:
WITH ProductWIthMaxVersion AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX(ProductVersion) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID, RecordID)
            AS MaxProductVersion
    FROM Product
)
SELECT
    PM.ProductID,
    PM.RecordID,
    MAX(PM.ReceivedDate) AS ReceivedDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN F.IsFirst = 1 THEN PM.UrgencyLevel END) AS FirstUrgencyLevel,
    MAX(CASE WHEN F.IsFinal = 1 THEN PM.UrgencyLevel END) AS FinalUrgencyLevel,
    MAX(CASE WHEN F.IsFirst = 1 THEN PM.InvestigationDate END) AS FirstInvestigationDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN F.IsFinal = 1 THEN PM.InvestigationDate END) AS FinalInvestigationDate,
    DATEDIFF(minute, MAX(PM.ReceivedDate), COALESCE(
        MAX(CASE WHEN F.IsFinal = 1 THEN PM.ResolvedDate END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN F.IsFirst = 1 THEN PM.ResolvedDate END)
        )) AS DurationInMinutes
FROM ProductWIthMaxVersion PM
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN PM.ProductVersion = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsFirst,
        CASE WHEN PM.ProductVersion = PM.MAXProductVersion THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsFinal
) F
GROUP BY PM.ProductID, PM.RecordID
ORDER BY PM.ProductID, PM.RecordID

A variation of the above is to use ROW_NUMBER() and ROW_NUMBER() descending to identify the first and final rows for each group.
WITH NumberedProductRows AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID, RecordID ORDER BY ProductVersion)
            AS RowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID, RecordID ORDER BY ProductVersion DESC)
            AS RowNumDesc
    FROM Product
)
...
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN NP.RowNum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsFirst,
        CASE WHEN NP.RowNumDesc = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsFinal
) F
...

ADDENDUM: It just occurred to me that a couple of extra CTEs, we can separately extract all first and all final rows, so that they may be directly joined in the final select. This eliminates the GROUP BY, greatly simplifies the select list, and allows for the easy extension  of the query to include additional joins.
WITH NumberedProductRows AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID, RecordID ORDER BY ProductVersion)
            AS RowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID, RecordID ORDER BY ProductVersion DESC)
            AS RowNumDesc
    FROM Product
),
FirstProductRows AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM NumberedProductRows
    WHERE RowNum = 1
),
LastProductRows AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM NumberedProductRows
    WHERE RowNumDesc = 1
)
SELECT
    F.ProductID,
    F.RecordID,
    F.ReceivedDate,
    F.UrgencyLevel AS FirstUrgencyLevel,
    L.UrgencyLevel AS FinalUrgencyLevel,
    F.InvestigationDate AS FirstInvestigationDate,
    L.InvestigationDate AS FinalInvestigationDate,
    DATEDIFF(minute, F.ReceivedDate, COALESCE(L.ResolvedDate, F.ResolvedDate))
        AS DurationInMinutes
FROM FirstProductRows F
JOIN LastProductRows L
    ON L.ProductID = F.ProductID
    AND L.RecordID = F.RecordID
ORDER BY F.ProductID, F.RecordID

Results (same for all of the above cases):



ProductID
RecordID
ReceivedDate
FirstUrgencyLevel
FinalUrgencyLevel
FirstInvestigationDate
FinalInvestigationDate
DurationInMinutes




1
17
2001-09-11 17:05:00
null
6
null
2001-09-11 17:59:00
179


2
13
2001-12-04 09:05:00
6
5
null
2001-12-04 10:19:00
182


3
71
2001-06-08 12:36:00
5
1
2001-06-08 12:36:00
2001-06-08 12:36:00
45


4
10
2001-05-01 11:00:00
1
1
2001-05-01 12:00:00
2001-05-01 12:15:00
90


5
21
2001-07-23 09:00:00
8
null
2001-07-23 10:15:00
2001-05-23 10:30:00
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Thanks @T N. I also have several other columns (>15) in the PRODCUT table that I simply want to display (e.g., UserAssigned, DeliveredTo, DeliveredBy, SignedBy ...etc) but are not necessary for the logic. How can I include those columns as well without having to write GROUP BY for each of the extra columns as that would be very tedious. (Also note that these extra columns have the same value for both versions of the product so the logic is not affected at all except that I want to include them in the display.)

Join the table back on again after all the calculations have been done, then you can avoid the additional grouping (but the tedious grouping method might still perform better - you might want to check).

I tested @T N's proposed solution above that applies CTE and it performs the logic fine except that it still returns  the result with both rows for the minimum version and maximum version instead of just one. I am testing to see if that might be due to the exra columns that I am selecting

I just updated the post with another variation that simplifies the final query and may be easier to extend.

Great thanks a mil @T N. I just quickly tested your solution that incorporates a couple of CTEs and I seem to get the desired output. Will take a closer look at the query and feedback if necessary :)

Would there be any cases where ResolvedDate is not set on either the first or final row, but is set in some intermediate row? Even if the first row contained a non-null ResolvedDate, would you prefer to always calculate DurationInMinutes based on the most recent non-null value? If so, you might need to add a LAST_VALUE() window function to the initial CTE and use that value for the duration calculation. See this db<>fiddle that shows this variation with some extra test data.

Yes thanks for mentioning that...there is such cases where ResolvedDate is not set on either the first or final row, but is set in some intermediate row and I also need to cater for that

Note that LAST_VALUE() with the IGNORE NULLS option is only available in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions, I think an OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ...) approach is needed. See this db<>fiddle.
